# Servicemix 7 Hibernate 5 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, apache-servicemix, persistence.xml

I am using Servicemix 7. I am trying to use JPA implemented by Hibernate in my project.
I have installed hibernate-release-5.2.16 in Servicemix.

META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl2" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="Nuernberg" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Nuernberg" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

From MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1561634626730
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
Built-By: ..
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ..
Bundle-SymbolicName: ..
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: ..
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-2.3.0.201405100607
```

Java Code:

```
private final static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Nuernberg");
```

I get

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Nuernberg
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.
java:61)[260:org.hibernate.javax.persistence.hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.
java:39)[260:org.hibernate.javax.persistence.hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final]
        at de.iteos.egov.advisadaptor.persistence.PersistenceFactory.<clinit>(Pe
rsistenceFactory.java:9)[241:adivstadaptor:1.0.0]
```